# Why absense of air (gas/atmosphere) increases friction while boring moon's rocks?

Tags: friction

Some science article says this: tehere would be more friction while boring moon's rocks because there is no atmosphere (air) - is this a fake or truth?

Why absense of air (gas/atmosphere) increases friction (let's pretend all other parameterts being equal)?

Comment: It'd help if you could cite an example article.  They're probably talking about a lack of lubricant or/and coolant.

Comment: Does this article help? https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/2005JE002538